# convert wsdl file to a usable library for php

Tags: php, .net, wsdl, wsdl2php

**Objective:**
To consume the WSDL file by a php web service client.

**Additional info:**
I have a WSDL (SOAP) file that is being generated by a third-party software. In introduction, I am using a .asp web service client and my method on how to consume the WSDL file (or invoke one of it's web service operation) is by means of converting the WSDL file into a library which can be referenced on my .asp project (I am using the wsdl.exe on Microsoft SDKs) and it works perfectly fine.

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to proceed with this kind of method for PHP. Is this achievable in PHP?  I've looked over the internet for a few days but I am still unable to find any relevant information about this. Can you guys help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you converting programming language ? not sure if you know PHP supports SOAP.

Comment: I dont get what you mean by convert programming language?  What I have done so far (on .asp/.net) was to generate an external libraries out of a wsdl file, then reference it to my project, and I can call/invoke that web service easily.  But I don't know how to achieve it when it comes to php.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume WSDL via PHP's [native SOAP client](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). If you are using PHP 4 , you have to use third party software such as [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

*sidenote:* For performance & stability, please use native functions as much as you can .

Comment: Hi Shivan! Do you have an online material or instructions on how can I consume a third-party web service using the WSDL distributed by them?